# How to demonstrate thread safety issue

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, jvm, locking

A coworker told me this Cache object needs to be made thread-safe:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

object Cache {
    private val data = mutable.Map[Int, String]()

    def get(key: Int): Option[String] = data.get(key)

    def set(key: Int, value: String): Unit = data(key) = value
}
```

This is my attempt to reproduce the issue:

```
def expensiveMethod(): String = {
    Thread.sleep(1)
    Thread.currentThread.getName
}

for (i <- 1 to 3) {
    new Thread(() => {
        val cachedValue = Cache.get(1)

        if (cachedValue.nonEmpty) {
            println(s"${Thread.currentThread.getName}: cached value = ${cachedValue}")
        } else {
            val newValue = expensiveMethod()
            Cache.set(1, newValue)

            val finalValue = Cache.get(1)
            println(s"${Thread.currentThread.getName}: final value = ${finalValue}")
        }
    }).start()
}

// Thread-2: final value = Some(Thread-2)
// Thread-3: final value = Some(Thread-2)
// Thread-1: final value = Some(Thread-2)
```

I'm trying to get my head around it. Three threads modify the data at the same time. Only one wins. Why is that a *problem*?

I do find it strange that in-between Thread-3 setting and reading the value, apparently Thread-2 has changed it. Is that the crux of the issue?

I tried using a lock but it didn't completely prevent that from happening, though it did seem to reduce the issue:

```
    def set(key: Int, value: String): Unit = data.synchronized { data(key) = value }
```

I also tried using `concurrent.TrieMap` instead of `mutable.Map`. It also appeared to reduce the issue but without running hundreds of tests I don't know how to be sure.

Comment: Your example code simply sets the same value, it never adds or removes anything from Map. It basically treats `Cache` as a glorified single-value array. That naturally can not showcase a thread-safety issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in-between Thread-3 setting and reading the value, apparently Thread-2 has changed it. Is that the crux of the issue?

Well, that is *one* of the issues. Your `expensiveMethod` can potentially be called several times, which is, at best, wasteful, but could potentially be more problematic if it has side-effects.

Like, if you were to keep statistics about your cache affinity, they'd be all off. Or you could cause a deadlock in the database ... etc.

A bigger (albeit, harder to reproduce on purpose) problem is `Map` implementation *itself* is not thread-safe.

This means that if one thread is doing `put`, while the other one is inside `get`, the result is undefined, and *could even cause the JVM itself to crash*.

To avoid the second (bigger) problem, you could just use java's `ConcurrentHashMap` (or `concurrent.TrieMap`, though, it would be less efficient).  That will guarantee always having a valid (albeit, possibly outdated) result from `get`, and assurance against random crashes, but does nothing to ease the first issue with potential redundant calls to `expensiveMethod`.

To avoid *that* (the wasted calls), you would need to synchronize the entire block:

```
    val cachedValue = Cache.synchronized { 
       Cache.get(1).getOrElse { 
        val value = expensiveMethod()
        Cache.set(1, value)
        value
       }
    }
```

Comment: Why is `TrieMap` less efficient than `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Maybe not ... I haven't looked at the exact implementation of either. Both are lock-free (good), but in general trie is less efficient than hash (but, like I said, haven't checked the actual implementations, the difference in this case could be negligible or not exist at all).

Comment: Since the point is to avoid redundant calls to `expensiveMethod`, can I not just wrap `expensiveMethod` in `synchronized`?

Comment: Also, isn't the performance loss from redundant calls to `expensiveMethod` on par with the performance loss from using a lock?

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge if you wrap it in `synchronized`, it will still be called multiple times, just not in parallel, so, no, you'd still be making redundant calls. Re. "on par with using a lock": that depends on how expensive your `expensiveMethod` really is. I would say, if it is comparable in cost with using a lock, chances are you don't need the cache at all. Unless, you are talking about possible lock contention on read - that could be a problem, but there are ways to deal with it too.

Comment: "could even cause the JVM itself to crash" — this is highly misleading statement. The JVM *itself* shall not crash because of such issue, that would be a violation of Java memory model. But the program can certainly crash (the `put()` method with throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, `NullPointerException` or something along those lines)

Comment: @user1643723 you might still be a young person :) Give it time, and I guarantee you will see your fair share of JVM crushes (as in core dumps) because of concurrency-related memory corruption in optimized mode. Till then, you should refrain from making categorical assertions like the one you made above.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is

1. Too simple
2. Has too few threads

If you want to "demonstrate" this specific issue by causing a crash or wrong output (purely for entertainment purposes), you need to simultaneously modify the map from multiple threads.

Java Map is quite fast, so you will have to run a large number of Threads, each one modifying the Map in infinite `while` loop (starting a Thread and executing an `expensiveMethod` are quite slow operations, so they reduce chance of reproducing the thread-safety issue).

In addition, you need to understand the internal structure of common `HashMap` implementation: simply setting the same key like this

```
Cache.set(1, newValue)
```

will not actually induce structural changes to the map — it will calculate a hash code and set array value at fixed offset — as you correctly observed such code is merely *racy*, but not necessarily wrong and will not usually result in crashes.

On other hand, if you concurrently add and remove random keys to Cache in tight loop, it will eventually crash with 100% possibility (this will probably happen in the code that writes values or resizes the underlying storage).

Note, that simply reading values is always 100% thread-safe. The crash is induced by mutation — but can come either from `get` or `put` method after mutation happens. A read-only `Map` and other strictly read-only structures are always thread-safe, even without synchronization (this property is actually exploited by CopyOnWriteArrayList).

---

That said, you should never rely on demonstrations and reproduction to evaluate and resolve thread-safety issues. As explained above, the difference between non thread-safe code, that "works" and the one, that crashes or miscalculates, is minuscule. Today all your tests are passing. Tomorrow, someone changes a single seemingly unrelated line and everything breaks.

Worse yet, you, personally, and your coworkers, programmers, testers etc. might never be able to reproduce a bug due to element of randomness inherent to thread-safety issues. But due to the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) your users might regularly experience unpredictable crashes and malfunctions — because they are the ones who run your program regularly and for much longer periods of time than you do.